# imacros javascript for loop not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop, imacros

JS noob here. I'd like to use the Javascript interface in imacros to execute a one-time prompt and then proceed to loop a macro according to the values recieved in the prompt. This is my Javascript:

```
iimPlay("QTMP3prompt.iim"); 
a = iimGetExtract(1);
b = iimGetExtract(2);
for (i=1;i<=b;i++){
iimSet("!VAR1",a);
iimSet("!VAR2",i);
iimPlay("QTMP3.iim");
}
```

This is QTMP3prompt.iim:

```
VERSION BUILD=8871104 RECORDER=FX
PROMPT "Unique string in entry title:" !VAR1
ADD !EXTRACT !VAR1
PROMPT "Number of entries" !VAR1 1
ADD !EXTRACT !VAR1
```

The first prompt should be a string of letters like *Barry* or *rry*. The second prompt should be a number, like *2*. This is QTMP3.iim:

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 90
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H3 ATTR=TXT:*{{!VAR1}}*
TAG POS=R{{!VAR2}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Add<SP>Derivative
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL FORM=ID:claf_form ATTR=TXT:Quicktime<SP>7,<SP>MediumBitrate:<SP>400<SP>kbpsDimensions:*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:claf_form ATTR=ID:claf_submit_button
TAG POS=1 TYPE=H3 ATTR=TXT:*{{!VAR1}}*
TAG POS=R{{!VAR2}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Add<SP>Derivative
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LABEL FORM=ID:claf_form ATTR=TXT:Audio<SP>only*MP3<SP>128kbps*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:claf_form ATTR=ID:claf_submit_button
```

The script seems to work fine until it reaches the for loop. But there it simply stops without once executing QTMP3.iim, and without any error message. Can anyone explain where my mistake is?

EDIT: I've determined that the problem occurs when I set variables a and b. They both get set as *Barry[EXTRACT]2*. So somehow iimGetExtract() is failing to parse the extract.

EDIT: Fixed that issue by using iimGetLastExtract() instead (odd, imacros Wiki said that was outdated). Now QTMP3.iim plays, but !VAR1 comes up undefined. So somehow I'm failing to set !VAR1 in the for loop.

EDIT: I swapped out !VAR1 and !VAR2 for my own user-defined variables *string* and *number*, respectively, and everything works. imacros Wiki says you can use iimSet to set built-in variables but evidently I was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Write down in this way:

```
ADD !EXTRACT {{!VAR1}}
```